# Is there a javascript library for displaying formulas

Tags: javascript

Are there any javascript libraries for displaying formulas that allow javascript events and styling to be added to parts of the formula?

Answer (score 1):

If is mathematical formulas what you are asking for you might want to take a look at: https://www.mathjax.org/